# Ls (-h) man page wrong on Yosemite?

Tags: bash, osx-mavericks, filesize, manpage

When i view the man page of ls on Yosemite I read the following:

```
-h      When used with the -l option, use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte in order to
        reduce the number of digits to three or less using base 2 for sizes.
```

But shouldn't that read **base 10**?

When I use the command **ls -lh** I see a files that is exactly 1000 bytes appearing as 1.0K (1 kilobyte). A file that is 999 bytes appears as 999B.

Isn't that base 10? Is that manual wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: “see a files that is exactly 1000 bytes appearing as 1.0K” No, the number of significant digits is such that 1.0K could be `ls`'s way of telling you that the file is slightly less than 1024 bytes. You should test what happens for 1022, 1024 and 1026 bytes.

Comment: 1022, 1024 and 1026 all show 1.0K

Comment: So I guess it is base 2 but rounded?

Comment: So there is no reason yet to suspect that your `ls` does not correctly use binary units (more properly called “kebibytes” and “mebibytes”) for `-h`. It could only be rounding the results to 2-3 significant digits, as you say.

Comment: This is even more strange output:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=999  count=1025`
`ls -lh`
`-rw-r--r--  1 kecso  285597778   1000 May 11 21:34 output.dat`
1000 what? :)

`ls -l`
`-rw-r--r--  1 kecso  285597778  1023975 May 11 21:34 output.dat`